# Placing text view on image view

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to place a single `TextView` over five `ImageViews`.the `ImageViews` are placed in a single `TableRow`.Is there any option available for that.Please help me..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried FrameLayout ?

Comment: no i'm using TableLayout..

Comment: Use a FrameLayout. Place your TextView inside that FrameLayout. Place your FrameLayout anywhere on the screen. It will always be on top.

Comment: Put your TableLayout as one layout in FrameLayout and TextView as the other layout. This will let you display TextView above TableLayout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this one.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:text="@string/text"
        android:textColor="#ff0000" />

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Relative layout firstly create a table layout for height and width set as wrap contents align gravity center similarly then add a textView also with gravity center this way textview will come over the table layout.

Answer (score 2):

Try these one:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
<TableLayout
   android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="84dp" >

        <ImageView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_icon_normal"/>


        <ImageView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_icon_pressed"/>
        <ImageView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/audio_normal"/>
        <ImageView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/audio_pressed"/>

        <ImageView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/back_normal"/>

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try insert this code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/image1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/image1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/image1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/image1"
        android:text="@string/text" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set main layout as `Relative Layout` inside that add your `Table Layout` then from the graphical layout add `TextView` wherever you need.

Answer (score 1):

What about using your TableLayout as "outer" layout and for each table cell you use a FrameLayout as "inner" layout. Using this FrameLayout, both ImageView and TextView will overlap.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer are correct. If you need it in table layout try this one.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tb1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tb1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:text="i am text on image views"
        android:textColor="#ff0000" />

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```